# How to get a property out of a JsonElement

Tags: c#, json, .net-7.0

I get from my data something like that:

```
ValueKind = Array : "[{"LookupId":370,"LookupValue":"Rahim, Zillur","Email":"ZRahim@ecgmc.com"}]"
```

VS says it is a JsonElement but I don't understand how to use JsonElement.TryGetProperty Method

```
 if (JsonElement.TryGetProperty("Email", out value))
{
    string email = value.GetString();
}
```

gives errors.

Anyone can help me with syntax to get from variable X
that shows value

```
ValueKind = Array : "[{"LookupId":370,"LookupValue":"Rahim, Zillur","Email":"ZRahim@ecgmc.com"}]"
```

how to get just the email property?

Comment: With 683 reputation, I expected a higher quality post. Please use the preview to check the formatting of your post. Don't say "Thanks in advance". Don't use tags in the title.

Comment: What does "gives errors" mean? Which error? This information is important. Please provide a [mre], that is: code we can copy and paste into our IDEs in order to reproduce the problem.

Comment: What is the difference between the "JSON" in the first code block and the "JSON" in the second code block? What is variable X? Questions over questions ...

Comment: What errors do you get, specifically? These usually provide indications of the issue, so for people to help, you should share what these "errors" are.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on the provided info your json element seems to be an array so you need to process it as one. For example:

```cs
var js = """
        [{"LookupId":370,"LookupValue":"Rahim, Zillur","Email":"ZRahim@ecgmc.com"}]
        """;
using var jsonDocument = JsonDocument.Parse(js);
var jsonElement = jsonDocument.RootElement;

var emails = jsonElement.EnumerateArray()
    .Select(element =>
    {
        if (element.TryGetProperty("Email", out var value))
        {
            return (Ok: true, value);
        }

        return (Ok: false, value);
    })
    .Where(t => t.Ok)
    .Select(t => t.value);
```

Comment: JsonElement jsonEle = (JsonElement)item.Fields.AdditionalData["AdditionalRecipients"];
var recipients = JsonSerializer.Deserialize<AdditionalRes[]>(jsonEle.GetRawText())   did it thank you